# React / Webpack app invalid element when component is moved to a new file?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a very simple React app working with Webpack with the following:

```
export const Row = (props) => {
  return <h1>This is a name</h1>;
};

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Row />
    )
  }
}
```

Ive moved Row to its own file and in my main file added this at the top:

```
import Row from './row';
```

However I get this error:

```
warning.js?0260:36 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `App`.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are exporting it as `named export` so you need to import it like this:

```
import {Row} from './row';
```

If you want to `import` that as `default`, then first you need to `export` that `function` default, like this:

```
const Row = (props) => {
  return <h1>This is a name</h1>;
};

export default Row;
```

Then you can `import` that in the way you are doing:

```
import Row from './row';
```

Check this article for more info on **[named and default import/export](https://danmartensen.svbtle.com/build-better-apps-with-es6-modules#es6-modules_1)**.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have to import React into sub files and also export the new module:

```
import React from 'react';

export const Row = (props) => {
  return <h1>This is a name</h1>;
};

module.exports = Row;
```